# objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess is not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexeddb

I Just started worked with indexedDB.

I am able to write the data inside object Store and get the data when hitting it first time.
when i am trying to hit again then i Observed that it goes fine with writting the data into DB but seems unable to call the OpenCursor.Success.

Can any one point out the gap please?

Here is my Code..

```
function clickMe()
{
alert("Yes am inside the function..");
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange;

try {
  var dbOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("MyDB");
  alert("congretss I Opened The DB as well..");

  dbOpenRequest.onsuccess = function(event){
  try {
     alert("I am inside the onsuccess Method");
     var db = dbOpenRequest.result;
     db.onerror=function(event){

     }; 

     var transaction = db.transaction(["My_ObjectStore"], "readwrite");

      transaction.oncomplete = function(e){

      };
      transaction.onabort = function(e){

      };
      transaction.onerror = function(e){

      };


      try {
        var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("My_ObjectStore");
       alert("Wait am trying to write the data in DB..");
        var objectId = new Date().getTime()
                    var data =([ {
                    "reference": "<a href='details.html'>DEV2014/557</a>",
                    "applicant": "Association",
                    "siteAddress": "631 Gregory Terrace, Bowen Hills",
                    "applicationType": "Decided Application",
                    "status": "Approved",
                    "action": "<a href='details.html' class='btn btn-primary'>View Details</a>",
                    "id": 1
                    },
                     {
                    "reference": "<a href='details.html'>DEV2014/557</a>",
                    "applicant": "Association",
                    "siteAddress": "631 Gregory Terrace, Bowen Hills",
                    "applicationType": "Decided Application",
                    "status": "Approved",
                    "action": "<a href='details.html' class='btn btn-primary'>View Details</a>",
                    "id": 2
                    }
                    ]);

        for(i in data)
        {
        var request = objectStore.add(data[i]);  
        }
        alert("Writing data is finished.."+request);

        //get all the data using cursor 
        objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
        alert("Now you can See the Data..");
         var cursor = event.target.result;

         if (cursor) {
            alert(cursor.value.id);

            cursor.continue();
            } 
             else {
            //alert("No more entries!");
                }     
           };   

        }catch(e){alert("error while writting the data");}



    }catch (e){         
            alert("An error occured when creating object store");
            writeError(e);
            }
     };

 dbOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
 try{
     var db = dbOpenRequest.result;
     var transaction = dbOpenRequest.transaction;
     var objectStore = db.createObjectStore("My_ObjectStore",{
        "keyPath": "id",
        "autoIncrement": true
      });
       }catch(e){alert("Error while crating object store");}
    };
  }
catch(e){alert("error");}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using try/catch blocks around your code? It is not needed. Why did you tag this question as jquery? This has nothing to do with jquery. Why are you logging 'congretss I Opened The DB as well..' when in fact you have not opened the db? why are you repeatedly defining callbacks to onerror at different scopes? Why are you using synchronous window.alert together with async code calls?  Why do you semi-randomly use semicolons to end your statements? Why are you using for-in to iterate over an array? Why is your code impossible to read?

Answer (score 0):

> i Observed that it goes fine with writting the data into DB

I just copy/pasted and tested your code, and the 1st write run fine, but the others don't (you can see your indexeddb content using browser debugging tools).

The reason:
You're setting the same primary key every time:

```
"id": 1
"id": 2
```

So i can't explain really why your open cursor fail after that (maybe because the your objectstore request gone in a error state?), but it seems to be the problem...

Comment: Thanks VIoz, I noticed the same previously.  when i changed the id from 1,2 to 3,4 and hit again then its shows the data 1,2,3,4!   Suppose say i have these data in indexDB i want to see these data how could i?   It seems Open Cursor is only get fired when some data is being written in DB other wise not.

Comment: You don't have to write anything, in the same code, if you remove the writing part between the two alert, it just works...

Comment: Thanks VIoz, Yeah its working fine. But If am going to get separate HTML file for writing the data and reading the data then I need to run both the file on user browser. Is there any way that whenever an User is going to hit the reading.html file then before calling reading.html, writting.html should get fired.  Actually i was looking to host this files on S3. now if someone is hitting this file then indexedDB should be initialized with the data first then only user will be able to get the data.

Comment: I recommend you to open a new detailed thread for this question, i cant help you about that cause i m not using JS. And please set this thread as 'answered'.